# Sort chat-list by the most recent message with firebase

Tags: android, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why I got stuck in a problem that the *chatList* is not sorting by the last message time or by the most recent message. I have tried storing `timestamp` in the database and *orderChildBy* timestamp but it still not working. not working means the list get not sort after every message and keep showing the list as the sorted after first message.

Look at the image how chats are disordered!

[image]

This is the way I created chatList in the `firebaseDatabase` in **ChatActiviy** on sendMessage:

```
    val timeAgo = Date().time

    val myTimeMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        myTimeMap["timestamp"] = timeAgo
        myTimeMap["id"] = friendId

    val friendTimeMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        friendTimeMap["timestamp"] = timeAgo
        friendTimeMap["id"] = currentUserID

    val chatListSenderReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).child(friendId)
        chatListSenderReference.keepSynced(true)
        chatListSenderReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
              override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
              }
              override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                       if(!p0.exists()){
                             chatListSenderReference.updateChildren(friendTimeMap)
                       }
    val chatListReceiverReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(friendId).child(currentUserID)
        chatListReceiverReference.updateChildren(myTimeMap)
        }
    })
```

On retrieving the chatlist in recyclerView, I am trying to get the users details for each userswho is presented as the child of currentUser in database. (Chatlist>>CurrentUserId)

### EDITED

```
  private fun retrieveChatList() {

    usersChatList = ArrayList()
    val userRef = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).orderByChild("timestamp")
    userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
    {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
        {
            (usersChatList as ArrayList<String>).clear()
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val userUid = dataSnapshot.key
                    if (userUid != null) {
                        (usersChatList as ArrayList<String>).add(userUid)
                    }
                }
                readChatList()
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun readChatList() {
    mUsers = ArrayList()
    val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
    userRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                mUsers?.clear()
                for (documentSnapshot in queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    val user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
                    for (id in usersChatList!!){
                        if (user.getUid() == id){
                            (mUsers as ArrayList<User>).add(user)
                        }
                    }
                }
                retrieveGroupChatList()
                chatListAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                chatListAdapter = context?.let { ChatListAdapter(it, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true) }
                recyclerViewChatList.adapter = chatListAdapter

            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "UserAdapter-retrieveUsers: ", e)
            }

}
```

And this is the chatListAdapter for friend info

```
private fun friendInfo(fullName: TextView, profileImage: CircleImageView, uid: String) {
        val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(uid)
        userRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (it != null && it.exists()) {
                        val user = it.toObject(User::class.java)
                Picasso.get().load(user?.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_pro_pic).into(profileImage)
                fullName.text = user?.getFullName()
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the picture of the realtime database and has a model class as **ChatList**, every time when I send or receive a message timestamp gets an update.

[image: ChatList]

and another picture of Users in the firestore and has a model class as [**Users**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu5t6m.jpg) .

## SOLUTION

I have a solution which works, Here i create or update a field as *lastMessageTimestamp* in the `Firestore` Users collection so the users now can sort by the *lastMessageTimestamp* .

```
   val timeAgo = Date().time
    
        val myFSMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
            myFSMap["timestamp"] = timeAgo
    
        val friendFSMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
            friendFSMap["timestamp"] = timeAgo
    
      //firebase chatlist references.
        val chatListSenderReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).child(friendId)
        val chatListReceiverReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(friendId).child(currentUserID)

      //Firestore Users references.
        val chatListSenderRef = fStore.collection("Users").document(currentUserID)
        val chatListReceiverRef = fStore.collection("Users").document(friendId)
    
        chatListSenderReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
           override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                 if(!p0.exists()){
                    chatListSenderReference.setValue(friendId)
                    //update the timestamp in Users collection
                    chatListSenderRef.update(myFSMap)
                 }
                    chatListReceiverReference.setValue(currentUserID)
                    chatListReceiverRef.update(friendFSMap)

           override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
               }
            }
        })
```

And at the time of reading, I use *orderBy* for Users

```
 val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").orderBy("lastMessageTimestamp" , Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

**But It is not the complete solution because it seems like that i read and write the *lastMessageTimestamp* each time on messaging, which can Increase the `Firebase Billing` Amount to huge scary numbers.**  so i still need of a solution.

Comment: would this helps: [Sorting firebase database by timestamp under a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981453/sorting-firebase-database-by-timestamp-under-a-key) and [Work with Lists of Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi i tried your suggetion but it works same no difference. i am gonna set bounty then try to answer for more reputation.

Comment: ok sorry @mr.groot  it was a bit unclear, i removed my answer as it was not what you need and i debugged your code you shared and it was working fine, the .orderByChild("timestamp") is working perfect, if i remove that line all items will be retrieved in the order saved in Firebase Database and if add it back all the items fetched by the timestamp.

Comment: I made also some timestamps changes manually in Firebase Console and again the ordering was correct. Each value in snapshot.children.forEach was correct. So just check the final mUsers data before adding them to adapter what order they have or what your doing with these data after adding them to adapter.

Comment: @MariosP Thanks and i appreciate your dedication about helping you wrote a very clear answer. And i will try what you suggested now . And please keep trying to answer for this .

Comment: Of course and let me know about your new results!

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick is orderBy id of message. Because the id which generated by firebase base on realtime + a few factors. So let's try order by Id instead of ur timestamp. (note: just id which generated by firebase)

Comment: There is no such id bro, i am talking about chatlist of users i have chatted with not messages.

Answer (score -1):

`enter code here`Saw your post don't know if it might be useful this late hour, provided the only thing you want from firestone is the user full identity, like the name, picture etc use the userid and save the full details to android database then retrieve the identity using the Id from chatlist firebase database that matches userid

Your code might look like this

Read from chatlist firebase database
Retrieve the sender Id and time
Use the id to retrieve already added info of the person on android database
your model should contain variable for retrieve time from database
Then add all to list
After that use a comparator to sort the arraylist/list base on time
Then notify adapter change

{` ......
userDao = UserDatabase.getUserDatabase(requireContext()).userDao();
}

```
private void sortChatList() {

    reference.child("chatlist").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).orderByChild("time").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            list.clear();;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String userID = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("chatid").getValue()).toString();
                 String time =  snapshot.child("time").getValue().toString();
                
                Chatlist chatlist = new Chatlist();


                UserDB userDB = userDao.getAll(userID);
                chatlist.setDate(time);
                chatlist.setUserName(userDB.getUserName());
                chatlist.setUserID(userID);
               


                list.add(chatlist);

            }
       
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Chatlist>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Chatlist o1, Chatlist o2) {
                    return Integer.valueOf(o2.getTime().compareTo(o1.getTime()));
                }
            });
            if (adapter != null) {

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            .........
```

`}